Uniswap V2 Router, Factory on amoy Test Network
what is the address of uniswap router on amoy test network as currenty uniswap doesn't support amoy network.

I don't think Amoy has any Uni contracts, you can deploy them for testing.

I forked factory contract and deployed that by mylself. The factory address is https://amoy.polygonscan.com/address/0x586a31a288e178369fff020ba63d2224cf8661e9#code
